# Updating an app without new permissions return empty permission request

Tags: android, android-manifest, developer-console

Please I want to make sure is this a normal behaviour when updating an app without new permission ?

The below is the screenshot of an example.

[image]

I was thinking that the app should auto update or at least dont show an empty request : myapplication need access to (empty line) than just say myapplication does not require any additional permissions ...

this is so weird no ? I mean even this box should contain new permissions added on this version or it should not appear

Thank you

Comment: I believe that on the latest version of the Google Play Store this functionality has changed and the box is no longer displayed when no permissions have changed. However, it was normal at the time for this dialog to be displayed.

Comment: my google play store is up to date and I am receiving this is so weired ...

Comment: What is your minimum SDK?

Comment: my minSdkVersion is 16, this is happening for the first time , the app was updated more than 20 times before ... We didnt add anything in the manifest or gradle

Comment: I have reported this issue to google support and they are investigating it , will return with the response as soon as I received it ..

Comment: @MohamedElloumi are you sure you have not removed any permissions which existed early ???

Comment: @Snehal Gongle Yes I am sure I am using git and I rechecked again the only thing I add is to make some new activities portrait mode only which should not need any permission !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic